# Using Django 2.0 So django.core.urlresolvers is no longer supported, how to make this try except block work?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to get the try except block to work with django 2.0.

```
def find_recurrence_i18n_js_catalog():
  # used cached version
    global _recurrence_javascript_catalog_url
    if _recurrence_javascript_catalog_url:
         return _recurrence_javascript_catalog_url

    # first try to use the dynamic form of the javascript_catalog view
    try:
        return urlresolvers.reverse(
            i18n.javascript_catalog, kwargs={'packages': 'recurrence'})
    except urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch:
        pass
```

I'm assuming that if I change it to this that it won't work:

```
# first try to use the dynamic form of the javascript_catalog view
    try:
        return reverse(
            i18n.javascript_catalog, kwargs={'packages': 'recurrence'})
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: This is entirely dependent on what you have imported. Did you import `reverse`?

Comment: Also, **never, ever, ever** do `except: pass`. That's hiding any useful information about what error is happening. Remove that try/except completely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in the original example it is using [from django.core import urlresolvers]

Answer (score 3):

Since [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#id3), you should import `reverse` and `NoReverseMatch` from `django.urls`:

```
from django.urls import reverse, NoReverseMatch

try:
    return reverse(
        i18n.javascript_catalog, kwargs={'packages': 'recurrence'})
except NoReverseMatch:
    pass
```